# save data from datagridview silverlight to database

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, sql-server-2008

How can I save all data from my `DataGrid` when my button save is clicked?

This is my code and say error:

```
string value = (new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<SampleCrudApp.MainPage.GenerateNumber>(grdOrders.ItemsSource)).Items[0].items1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get data back from the datagrid view
        //assuming my gridview is bound to ObservableCollection<User>
        var users= dataGridView1.DataSource as ObservableCollection<User>;
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            //perform the save
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example so you can see how to get the data:

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            values.Add(cell.Value)
        Next

        sSQL = "INSERT INTO Table (value1,value2,value3) " & _
               "VALUES (" & values(0) & "," & values(1) & "," & values(2) & ")"

        '[...]
    Next
```

You must keep in mind the types of each column to use the proper format in each case.